# How to reregister for IO Completion ports for a handle

Tags: winapi, pipe, port, named, completion

I have a Windows named pipe that I create with `CreateFile` (the server side was created using `CreateNamedPipe`). I use IO completion ports to read/write data asynchronously on both ends.

I need to send these handles to other processes after they've been opened. I tried to call `CloseHandle` on the handle returned from `CreateIoCompletionPort`, and then in the other process call `CreateIoCompletionPort` again. However it always fails and `GetLastError` returns 87 (`ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`).

I can also reproduce this in just one process, see below. Note there are no outstanding reads/write to the object before I send it.

```
std::wstring pipe_name = L"\\\\.\\pipe\\test.12345";
HANDLE server = CreateNamedPipeW(
    pipe_name.c_str(),
    PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
    PIPE_TYPE_BYTE | PIPE_READMODE_BYTE,
    1,
    4096,
    4096,
    10000,
    NULL);
SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES security_attributes = {
    sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES), NULL, TRUE};
HANDLE client = CreateFileW(
    pipe_name.c_str(), GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
    0,
    &security_attributes,
    OPEN_EXISTING,
    SECURITY_SQOS_PRESENT | SECURITY_ANONYMOUS | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
    NULL);
ULONG_PTR key = 1;
HANDLE comp_port = CreateIoCompletionPort(client, NULL, key, 1);

BOOL b1 = CloseHandle(comp_port);

comp_port = CreateIoCompletionPort(client, NULL, key, 1);
if (comp_port == NULL) {
  int last_err = GetLastError();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Referring to the [documentation for CreateIoCompletionPort](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363862(v=vs.85).aspx):

> A handle can be associated with only one I/O completion port, and after the association is made, the handle remains associated with that I/O completion port until it [the handle] is closed.
>
> [...] The I/O completion port handle and every file handle associated with that particular I/O completion port are known as references to the I/O completion port. The I/O completion port is released when there are no more references to it.

In other words, closing the I/O completion port handle doesn't achieve anything.  The I/O completion port still exists and is permanently associated with the pipe handle.  What you're attempting simply isn't possible; you will need to rearchitecture.

Note also:

> It is best not to share a file handle associated with an I/O completion port by using either handle inheritance or a call to the DuplicateHandle function.  Operations performed with such duplicate handles generate completion notifications. Careful consideration is advised.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have commented above on what I tried with the idea there of calling CreateFile before closing the handle.

Comment: You're right, looks like this isn't possible with IOCP.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for [CreateIoCompletionPort](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363862.aspx) suggests what you're trying to accomplish isn't possible. All handles associated with an I/O completion port refer to the port and as long one is still open the port remains alive:

> The I/O completion port handle and every file handle associated with that particular I/O completion port are known as *references to the I/O completion port*. The I/O completion port is released when there are no more references to it. Therefore, all of these handles must be properly closed to release the I/O completion port and its associated system resources. After these conditions are satisfied, close the I/O completion port handle by calling the **CloseHandle** function.

It should work if you create a new handle that's not associated with the I/O completion port with CreateFile and then pass it to the other processes with DuplicateHandle. Or just call CreateFile in the other process directly.

Comment: Good idea, I tried duplicating the handle before closing it, but that seemed to have kept a reference. I was wary about calling CreateFile again, because if the other side is being sent then it could lead to both sides of the pipe being closed.

I tried calling CreateFile a second time before I call CloseHandle on the first client handle and completion port. CreateFile returns INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE and GetLastError is PIPE_ERROR_BUSY. This is happening even though I changed nMaxInstances to PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES. Per MSDN, I tried looping and calling WaitNamedPipe but that didn't fix things.

Comment: @JohnSeif: PIPE_ERROR_BUSY is typically caused by the server end failing to call ConnectNamedPipe.

Comment: Does the server have to call ConnectNamedPipe? I don't call it and the first CreateFile success fine. My problem is I don't know how often to call it in the server because it doesn't know when the client will switch processes.

Comment: I finally got it to work, I didn't realize I have to call CreateNamedPipe once per instance. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Looks like the server-client pairs of handles have separate view of the data. I was looking for only one view, even as I send handles across to different processes, so calling CloseHandle won't work.